# Incrementing digits in a string in python

Tags: python, string, digits

Given a string, how can I increment that string by an x number, lets say I have 2345 and I want to increment each digit by 4 so that it is converted to 6789?

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? See the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for more info on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Convert the string to an actual integer, add 4444 to it, then convert back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 4 units to each digit of 2345 is the same as adding 4444 to 2345.

For this you will have to convert the numbers to strings, but it is not a problem.

My proposed solution is something like this:

```
def my_func(number, digit_addition):
    number = str(number)
    digit_addition = str(digit_addition)
    
    number_addition = digit_addition * len(number)

    return int(number) + int(number_addition)

print(my_func(2345, 4))
#6789
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

```
def add(number: str, addition: str) -> string:
    return [(int(item) + int(addition)) for item in number if (int(item) + int(addition)) < 10 else ((int(item) + int(addition)) - 10)].join()
```

add(5486, 2)

#7608

add(8913, 5)

#3468

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Computer memory works by holding blocks of tiny electrical charges (the famous 'ones and zeros' - really charge and no charge), so everything needs to represented using these. We need to somehow represent the number 6 or the letter p using these electrical charges.

We call one of these tiny electrical charges a bit, and 8 of them (normally) is a byte.

Python integers are represented in RAM directly as binary numbers, and they use four bytes. Imagine a `0` as no charge and `1` as a charge. For example the number 6 is represented in RAM as `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110`.

Strings are represented in RAM as binary numbers that represent UTF-8 characters. UTF-8 is a common way for characters (the letter p, the number 6, a smile emoji) to be represented in memory. The letter p is represented as `01110000`, the number 6 is actually represented as `00110110` (54 in binary).

So telling the processor to add `...00000110` and `...00000110` would result in `...00001100`, which is 12. Telling it to add `00110110` and `00110110` (two "6" strings) would come to `01101100` (108), which is actually a small letter l. This obviously makes no sense.

So, you need to convert the strings to integers (tell the python interpreter to turn `00110110` into `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110`), do the math, and then convert them back again:

```py
num1 = "2345"
num2 = "4444"

ans = int(num1) + int(num2)
sring_ans = str(ans)

print(sring_ans)   // 6789
```